# How do I add or amend a node based on another XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two files (File1):

```
<institution>
<ukprn>1234</ukprn>
<course>
    <courseID>1</courseID>
    <courseaim>X99</courseaim>
</course>
<student>
    <birthdate>30/10/1985</birthdate>
    <instance>
        <OWNINST>123456|5</OWNINST>
        <FC>1</FC>
        <STULOAD>100</STULOAD>
        <elq>4</elq>
        <MODE>31</MODE>
    </instance>
</student>
<student>
    <birthdate>01/02/1999</birthdate>
    <instance>
        <OWNINST>654321|1</OWNINST>
        <FC>2</FC>
        <elq>2</elq>
    </instance>
    <instance>
        <OWNINST>654321|2</OWNINST>
        <FC>6</FC>
        <elq>1</elq>
    </instance>
</student>
</institution>
```

And (File2):

```
<studentstoamend>
    <STUDENT><OWNINST>123456|5</OWNINST><MODE>01</MODE></STUDENT>
    <STUDENT><OWNINST>111112|1</OWNINST><MODE>31</MODE></STUDENT>
</studentstoamend>
```

For OWNINSTs in File2 I need to update the mode in File1.  Where there is no mode in File1 then I need to add one in after the ELQ node.

I am convinced that this is not difficult in XML stylesheets but can't seem to do it.

---

Edit 05/10/2015 11:03

So, thanks to @bknights I the XSLT now inserts MODE where missing which is great.  I have managed to adjust the file to parse.  The next issue is that it removes the instance tags so everything moves up to the student level.  I have tried fiddling with it but can't get it to not do that.  Can anyone assist please?  This is the code I now have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="studentRefs" match="STUDENT" use="OWNINST"/>
<xsl:variable name="studentRefs" select="document('MCDATE - students to amend.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="Instance">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="OWNINST"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:if test="count(MCDATE)= 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="checkMcdate">
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="OWNINST"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template> 

        <xsl:template match="MCDATE">
            <xsl:param name="id"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="checkMcdate">
                <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="default" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template name="checkMcdate">
                <xsl:param name="id"/>
                <xsl:param name="default" select="''"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$studentRefs/studentstoamend">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="count(key('studentRefs', $id)) = 1">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="key('studentRefs', $id)/MCDATE"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="not($default='')">
                            <MCDATE><xsl:value-of select="$default"/></MCDATE>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good point, apologies Michael!

Comment: "*Where there is no mode in File1 then I need to add one in after the ELQ node.*" What value should this added node have, when there is no matching instance in File2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. Not parsed. It will at least get you some concepts to look up.

```
<xsl:key name="studentRefs" match="STUDENT" use="OWNINST"/>
<xsl:variable name="studentRefs" select="document('studentRefs.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="instance">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:with-param name="id" select="OWNINST"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
   <xsl:if test="count(MODE)= 0">
   <xsl:call-template name="checkMode">
      <xsl:with-param name="id" select="OWNINST"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
...

<xsl:template match="MODE">
   <xsl:param name="id"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="checkMode">
      <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="default" select="."/>
   </xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="checkMode">
  <xsl:param name="id"/>
  <xsl:param name="default" select="''"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$studentRefs/studentstoamend">
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="count(key('studentRefs', $id)) = 1)>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('studentRefs', $id)/MODE"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="not($default='')">
      <MODE><xsl:value-of select="$default"/></MODE>
     </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks very much but it doesn't work, as you say it isn't parsed and I've tried but can't get it to run.

Comment: It says the value of the attribute "test" associated with an element type "xsl:when" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: <xsl:copy-of select="key('studentRefs', $id)/MCDATE"/>  This is the bit it has a problem with

Comment: Ooh, it works except that it removes the instance tag and puts everything that was in it at student level